# Jitpack working with www. but not without it only for me

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build, jitpack

I just started at a new job where we are building an app in React Native. When building the android version I was getting errors that said

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:0.12.+.
```

My coworkers weren't getting this error but I was. I found [this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/2229#issuecomment-429756596) solution on github issues that ended up fixing the problem for me, but we don't want to commit a change to our build process without understanding why it is happening or why the fix works. Does anybody have more insight to what was happening or why the fix worked?

We are using Gradle and it is properly configured under allprojects -> repositories -> `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Jitpack is having DNS issues according to [this](https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/3973) Github issue. My coworkers likely have the dependencies cached so that would be why it is working on their machines but not mine